zsh terminal: scripts that are available on the path, are not suggested by autocomplete
I've placed several scripts at: ~/bin/scripts.
when in bash, if I place the script there, and put the location in the path, I can type out half the script name and hit tab, and the rest of the script name or scripts with matching names will be listed.
However, on this new OSX install which uses zsh by default, this doesn't appear to work the same. only some of the scripts are listed, and I cannot figure out how to get it all working like I had in bash.
I would prefer not to use a lot of helper tools, I should be able to get this working with modifications to the .zshrc alone, shouldn't I?  I do happen to have ohmyzsh installed.

What is the value of $PATH?

I cannot reproduce this; all of the executable scripts in my equivalent directory are available for completion. But: I don't normally have oh-my-zsh running. OMZ adds a huge number of aliases and functions and such to the completion namespace - you may be running into partial or full collisions with your script names.

chmod 755 /bin/scripts/* ?

If the directory of the script is in the PATH, and the script is executable, this does work, unless you have fiddled with the completion system or have some malevolent precmd function, which interfers with your attempt. For debugging, create a new zsh which does not source your .zshrc (zsh -f), set up your PATH manually and check the behaviour. If it still does not work, post a screenshot which demonstrates that you have set up everything correctly.

sorry guys. I tried again today and I'm not getting a repro. I'm not sure what is going on.

For trying to reproduce the issue: Creater a new directory, put some executable into it, add the directory to your PATH, and see whether you get completion on the new executable. If you don't, type rehash and try again. If it still doesn't work, make a screenshot and let us see what you were doing.
